# create cup on cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I am creating one game in iphone in that I want to through any object in one box . link paper toss game. in this application user thorough paper in a glass. same think i want to do .

Can any one know how to create this game . any sample code to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Translated: Hi Everyone. I am creating a game on iPhone (iOS) in which I want to throw an object into a box, like the Paper Toss game (in this app, the user throws paper into a glass. I want to do the same).  Does anyone know how to create this game, or would they be able to provide any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you'll likely want to use a game framework such as Cocos2d or Sparrow, in combination with a physics engine such as Box2D or Chipmunk.

I'm not at my development computer at the moment, but I'll post some helpful links when I get there in a few hours.

Comment: Please provide link as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordaan that a game library might help. My choice of tool will be cocos2D.
You can follow the discussion "Best method for paper toss game" on [Cocos2D forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21966)